# Intercepting requests and providing resources to Xamarin.Forms.WebView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to show some XHTML documents that reference some resources (style sheets, scripts, images, etc). These resources are local, but they do not exist on the file system - instead, they are generated by my application.

Using `Android.Webkit.WebView` and `Android.Webkit.WebViewClient`, I can intercept requests and provide these resources flawlessly, using something like this:

```
internal class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{           
    public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, string url)
    {
        /* logic to create a resource stream for the requested url */
        return new WebResourceResponse (mimeType, encoding, generatedStream);
    }
}
```

Can I achieve something similar using `Xamarin.Forms.WebView` and its related classes? If so, how? I haven't noticed in the API documentation any methods that look like they provide equivalent behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Xamarin.Forms** **WebView** control is very basic at present.  The [class members](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.WebView%2f*) show that you **wouldn't** be able achieve what you are wanting to do.

You can load a **HTML** resource etc [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/webview/) that is quite useful in determining how to reference local files, if you do decide and go down that route.

Do note, however, that in **Xamarin.Forms v1.2.2.6243** on **Android** the **Source** property is incorrectly set for **URLs**.  For instance, if you navigate to *www.yahoo.com* and do a few clicks on that site, you will see some query string parameters etc.  However, on **Android** this always comes back as **Source** property being *www.yahoo.com*.  *Xamarin* have created a temporary fix for this, however you have to include and implement your own custom renderer at present to overcome this.